# YouTube not working on Ubuntu 10.04

Tags: ubuntu, youtube

Yesterday I applied the latest updates to my Ubuntu 10.04 machine, as I routinely do whenever the update manager suggests it. Now on Firefox 3.6.12 YouTube videos are not working. I just get a black rectangle where the video and all the control buttons are supposed to be.

Does anyone know how I should go about diagnosing the problem?

This happens every time I apply the latest updates, and I usually trawl around the internet or this site and come up with something. On this occasion though I can't remember what I did last time or where to find it.

Comment: I have the most recently updated version of 10.10 (the newer release), and YouTube works great in Chrome 9 Dev. Try a different browser, maybe that would work. Also, what version of the Flash Player plugin do you have installed?

Comment: @Blender, looking in the Manage Content Plugins, there were none in use. Where they all went to I don't know. But reloading the adobe flash installer seems to have fixed the problem. Thank you for you help.

Comment: Put your comment in an answer. Wait a day then select it as the correct answer. This helps other people who might have a similar problem and you'll probably get some upvotes on your answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I looked in the Manage Content Plugins dialogue off the Tools menu, and found there were no plugins in use. Where they all went to I don't know.

Selecting All Plugins, and then clicking on the pull-down next to Flash Video enabled me to reinstall the Adobe Flash software. On retrying, the YouTube videos started working, so I presume this fixed the problem.